# How to use *args with list of ints?

Tags: python, variables, arguments

I have a list of user integers:

```
user1 = [4,5,2,3,4]
user2 = [4,2,1,3,4,4,2]
```

I want to use *args to count avg.

```
def avg(*args):
  sum=0
  for num in avg:
     sum =+ num
  result = sum/len(avg)
  return result
```

And if I call it this way:

```
avg(4,5,2,3,4)
avg(4,2,1,3,4,4,2)
```

everythig is fine. Code works.
But I still need to change a code to do that. I don't understand how to use that *args.

For example, user put 3 int in table my code do something like that:

```
avg(userTable) // and just put a 3 args in fun
```

Can someone explain me how can I do it? I need to use variable arguments for benchmark.

One of my attempts:

```
pkt = [44,23,0,22]
def avg(*pkt):
    suma = 0
    count = len(pkt)
    for i in range(len(pkt)):
        if pkt[i] != 0:
            print(i)
            sum = sum + pkt[i]
        else:
            count = count - 1
    result= pkt[0] + pkt[1] + sum
    result= result/(count+2)
    print(result)
    return result


avg(pkt)
```

but i got an error in count line.

Comment: I think you want `suma = 0` instead of `sum = 0`? Actually -- `suma` is better to you don't clobber the built-in function.

Comment: You need to decide whether your function accepts a singe list or an undetermined number of individual arguments. You can't have both.

Comment: it will be sum. So, how can I use *args function from the console?

Comment: The way you have defined the function, you can call it with `avg(*pkt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def avg(*args)` means that your function takes several arguments, but calling `avg(pkt)` passes a *list* to the function. You need to unpack that list with `avg(*pkt)` so its contents are passed individually to the function - or of course define the function as `def avg(args)` so it accepts a list as its only argument.

Comment: awesome ! One * and everything is clear now! Thank u for explanarion and ur time ;)

Answer (score 2):

I think an example is the best way to showcase `args` and `kwargs`. Notice the following:

```py
def foo(*args):
    print(args)

foo(1, 2, 3)
```

outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

---

```py
def bar(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

bar(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

outputs:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

---

```py
def foobar(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args', args)
    print('kwargs', kwargs)

foobar(1, 2, 3, d=4, e=5, f=6)
```

outputs:

```
args (1, 2, 3)
kwargs {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```

---

In short, `args` allows functions to take any unnamed variables and `kwargs` allows functions to take any named variables. However, it is not the name `args` and `kwargs` that give them this special property, but rather the explicit definition of each with `*` and `**`:

```py
def foo(*lol):
    print(lol)

foo(1, 2, 3)
```

outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Checkout the Python documentation on them [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

---

The concept above also works for unpacking other objects, such as `list` and `set`. Notice:

```py
print([1, 2, 3])  # >>> [1, 2, 3]
```

where

```py
print(*[1, 2, 3]) # >>> 1 2 3
```

The above is the equivalent of passing three separate arguments to the `print` function, so it is the same as doing:

```py
print(1, 2, 3)
```